# How to get back from RAM1 to ROM after setting the bank bit to 1

Tags: memory

[Mapping more than 64kb of address space](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/mapping-more-than-64kb-of-address-space)

regarding cjs answer: How to get back from RAM1 to ROM after setting the bank bit to 1? the next instruction from the program counter would be read from RAM1 instead ROM, isnt it?

Comment: Your question could be improved by including enough information to make it stand alone. Perhaps explain the premise of the other question and summarise tofro's solution.

Comment: Generally with bank switching you call a subroutine in a common area that actually does the bank switch so that you are not changing the very memory bank you’re executing from - “pulling the rug from underneath yourself” so to speak. That’s not to say you can’t do it - but it must be done carefully!